# Problem getting the page includes mapped towards my own ModuleName

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-1.4

I'm having problem using the page includes for setting up a header component called TelenorHeader under my own areaName (Telenor).

In my page template "TelenorPage" under the metadata schema I have added an include to:
system/include/telenorheader

The setup for the rest of the page template is:
Page View Name : Telenor:TelenorPage
I have also tried to setup some Regions Metadata here to:
- Region View Name: Telenor:TelenorHeader
- Region Name: Telenor:TelenorHeader
[image]

The TelenorHeader page it is setup with the include page template (no meta data).
[image]

In my TelenorModuleInitializer I have this setup

```
@ComponentScan("no.telenor.modules.Telenor")
@Component
@RegisteredViewModels({
// PAGE TEMPLATES
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "TelenorPage", modelClass = PageModelImpl.class),
// REGION TEMPLATES
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "TelenorHeader", modelClass = RegionModelImpl.class),
// COMPONENT TEMPLATES
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "TelenorTeaser", modelClass = TelenorTeaserModel.class),
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "TelenorHeaderTop", modelClass = TelenorHeaderTop.class),
})

@ModuleInfo(name = "Telenor MVC module", areaName = "Telenor", description = "DXA module which contains Telenor MVC")
public class TelenorModuleInitializer extends AbstractInitializer {
@Override
protected String getAreaName() {
    return "Telenor";
}
}
```

Under the WEB-INF/Views/Telenor/Region
I have created the TelenorHeader.jsp View

When I run it all the Pages and Entities views that I have under my Telenor folder works as intended but for the Region I get an error telling me it is trying to get the region view from the Core folder.
Why is it not mapping correctly to my custom Telenor module?

```
16:05:38.263 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR c.s.w.c.impl.taglib.dxa.RegionTag - Error while processing region tag
javax.servlet.ServletException: File [/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Region/TelenorHeader.jsp] not found
at     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:407) [jasper.jar:8.5.4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For include Pages, the (qualified) View Name is obtained from the Page Title. See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/issues/3